# Unable to install googlemaps api through command line Python (Windows 8)

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, command-line

I am unable to install the Google API client through the command line, as '$' is not recognized. I have installed python. Any input would be great. 
[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dQSV.jpg)

Comment: `$` is linux command line promt, you haven't to write it

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a Linux prompt. The actual command is `pip install -U googlemaps`.